# Typescript JSDoc events are global

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I've been trying to get JSDoc working with TypeScript and for the most part seem to have it working as long as I use the correct naming conventions.

Thanks mostly to this post: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/504

I can't seem to figure out how to document events so that they're documented as being part of the class as apposed to being global.

This is what the JS output from TypeScript looks like:

```
    var Cars;
    (function (Cars) {
        /**
        * Represents the main car class
        * @class Cars.Car
        */
        var Car = (function () {
            /**
            @event Cars.Car#started
            @summary The event is fired when the car starts
            */
            function Car() {
                this._func_started = null;
            }
            return Car;
        })();
        Cars.Car = Car;
    })(Cars || (Cars = {}));
```

I realize the class itself doesn't make much sense, but the @event syntax I would have thought would document an event on the Car class. Instead it seems to be global?

Must admit I'm not having a fun with TypeScript and JSDoc :(

Comment: The compiler does not parse the JSDoc to try to figure out where sub-parts of a comment should be placed. The rule is simply "emit comments next to the declaration that they were attached to". What are you expecting to be emitted where?

Comment: If I read correctly, the event is indicated to be of type `Cars.Car` and is named `started`? So I do not think it is seen as global? A little more explanation of what you expect to see would be helpful.

Comment: I ran the code fragment you've shown with jsdoc 3.2.2 and I do get the ``started`` event on the page for the ``Car`` class.